# How to use computeDistanceBetween()?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using Google Maps Android API Utility Library to calculate distance between two points ,I have seen the docs but I don't know where I am doing wrong. The distance measured between two points are much greater . Below is my code

```
ParseGeoPoint requesterLocation = object.getParseGeoPoint("requesterLocation");
LatLng from = new LatLng(userLocation.getLatitude(),userLocation.getLongitude());
LatLng to = new LatLng(requesterLocation.getLatitude(),requesterLocation.getLongitude());

//Double distanceInKm = userLocation.distanceInKilometersTo(object.getParseGeoPoint("requesterLocation"));
Double dis = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(from,to);
Double disOneDp = (double) Math.round(dis * 10) / 10;
listViewContent.add(String.valueOf(disOneDp) + " Km");
```

Result is 12627.6 km where it should be 29.4km

Comment: then,I dont know whats the use of this. Can you please tell me how to get minimum distance?

Comment: what do you see on the logcat if you call `Log.d(TAG, "from " + from + ", to " + to)`?

Comment: I think the problem is with your coordinates as you've used `computeDistanceBetween` in the correct way and as result is in metres, still `12627.6/1000 != 29.4`.

Comment: i have double checked i am doing all good

Comment: @pskink  this is what my logs are showing  27.498242,90.12489

Comment: Either this is not the complete log or you've errors, because this is just a single latLng, where's the other one?

Comment: call `Log.d` i wrote

Comment: by the way can anyone of you please check that am i doing the conversion right ie  from GeoPoint to LatLng

Comment: D/geo: lat/lng: (27.58583053,90.20794596) lat/lng: (27.498242,90.12489)

Comment: Your latlng seems fine.

Comment: @pskink this is aerial distance and it is much shorter than road distance and btw i want road distance

Comment: see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro or https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start then

Answer (score 2):

**Here getting distance in kilometers (km)**

```
private double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
double theta = lon1 - lon2;
double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(lat1)) 
                * Math.sin(deg2rad(lat2))
                + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1))
                * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2))
                * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));
dist = Math.acos(dist);
dist = rad2deg(dist);
dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
return (dist);}

private double deg2rad(double deg) {
return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);}

private double rad2deg(double rad) {
return (rad * 180.0 / Math.PI);}
```

Comment: I tried this and i think this will return aerial distance and i want minimum roadDistance

Comment: @dhami_ji You should have mentioned that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

**Here getting distance in meters (m)**
try these methods will help you find radius based distance and if you are looking for distance by road try to use google map API for distance [GOOGLE MAP MATRIX API , ROAD BASED DISTANCE AND TIME TUTORIAL](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/driving-distance-and-travel-time-duration-between-two-locations-in-google-map-android-api-v2/).!

```
private float distance(double currentlatitude, double currentlongitude, double originLat, double originLon) {

    float[] results = new float[1];
    Location.distanceBetween(currentlatitude, currentlongitude, originLat, originLon, results);
    float distanceInMeters = results[0];

    return distanceInMeters;
}
```

**Here getting distance in Meters(m)**

```
Location startPoint=new Location("locationA");
startPoint.setLatitude(17.372102);
startPoint.setLongitude(78.484196);

Location endPoint=new Location("locationA");
endPoint.setLatitude(17.375775);
endPoint.setLongitude(78.469218);

double distance=startPoint.distanceTo(endPoint);
```

Comment: is it aerial or road distance?

Comment: @dhami_ji did you see the links i posted?

Comment: @pskink yes i did but I am still struggling on how to use it, but i think this will give me the road distance

Comment: @dhami_ji what "this"? this answer?

Comment: pass it your current location and then final location.@dhami_ji .? and if you have any query then do let me know.!

Comment: Pretty sure this is direct distance, not along roads

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks mate for this knowledge, could you please explain how to get road distance then.?

Comment: You would use the Distance matrix API and parse out the sum of the distances https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro

Answer (score 0):

I think you are actually doing it wrong.
According to the official [Google map utils documentation](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.html#computeDistanceBetween-LatLng-LatLng-) ;

> ```
> computeDistanceBetween(LatLng from, LatLng to)
> ```
>
> Returns the distance between two LatLngs, in meters.

The result is returned in meters, so you should convert it to kilometers like so;

```
Double disInMeters = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(from,to);
Double disInKilometers = disInMeters / 1000;
// Double disOneDp = (double) Math.round(dis * 10) / 10;
listViewContent.add(String.valueOf(disInKilometers) + " Km");
```